# When exactly SIGTERM is sent to Spring Boot App process in a container when preStop hook is used?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I'm trying to understand how traffic can be routed to a pod that has begun shutdown process.

In Spring Boot docs it is mentioned that

> Once the pre-stop hook has completed, SIGTERM will be sent to the container and graceful shutdown will begin, allowing any remaining in-flight requests to complete.

[Kubernetes Container Lifecycle](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/deployment.html#cloud-deployment-kubernetes-container-lifecycle)

But in Kubernetes docs we have

> The Pod's termination grace period countdown begins before the PreStop hook is executed, so regardless of the outcome of the handler, the container will eventually terminate within the Pod's termination grace period. No parameters are passed to the handler.

[Container hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks)

In Kubernetes docs it say `The Pod's termination grace period countdown begins before the PreStop hook is executed` which means SIGTERM was send before the hook is called. Isn't this in contradiction to Spring Boot which says `Once the pre-stop hook has completed, SIGTERM will be sent to the container`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens in the following order:

1. Count down for termination grace period starts
2. Pre stop hook starts executing
3. Pre stop hooks finished
4. SIGTERM is issued to the container, Spring Boot starts shutting down (possible waiting if graceful shutdown is configured)

If at any point in time the grace period is exceeded SIGKILL is issued and all processes are terminated.

Comment: How #1 can happen when SIGTERM is not sent?

Comment: The count down is handled internally by kubernetes - not your spring application.

Comment: Yes, I know. When Kubernetes starts the count down it should send the SIGTERM. In your order SIGTERM is sent after the PreStop is finished (#4). There is a gap! Just consider the case where in PreStop we have something like `command: ["sh", "-c", "sleep 10"]`. Does it mean that SIGTERM is not sent because its sleeping for that duration?

Comment: You are right, the sigterm is sent 10s later in that case, so the application has 20s left if no explicit grace period is configured.

Comment: Understood, the behavior is mentioned in [Hook handler execution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#hook-handler-execution)